# Because of the setInterval Javascript command, my photo won't slowly appear on my webpage

Tags: javascript, image, setinterval, caption, heading

My webpage has a heading that starts out small.  But it grows in size as it approaches the screen.  Then it's supposed to float to the top of the screen.  While the heading approaches the top of the screen, a photo is supposed to fade into view.  There is also a caption that is supposed to fade into view.  But neither the photo or the caption will fade into view.  And I don't know why.

YouTube_Advanced_Heading.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Advanced Heading</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = 
"YouTube_Advanced_Heading.css">
</link>
<script language = "JavaScript" src = "YouTube_Advanced_Heading.js">
</script>
</head>
<body id = "BColor" onload = "Setup()">
<h1 id = "My_Heading">The Winner Of The Video Response Wars Is:</h1>
<img id = "My_Image" src = "Bootsie.jpg">
</img>
<p id = "Winner_Text">Crazy Josh Cravy</p>
<input id = "Point_Values" type = "hidden">
</input>
<input id = "Raise_My_Text" type = "hidden">
</input>
<input id = "S_Collection" type = "hidden">
</input>
<input id = "F_Photo" type = "hidden">
</input>
<input id = "T_Height" type = "text">
</input>
</body>
</html>
```

YouTube_Advance_Heading.css

```
#BColor {
background-color: yellow;}
#My_Heading {
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
left: 400px;
font-size: 32px;}
#My_Image {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 475px;
width: 400px;
height: 300px;}
#Winner_Text {
position: absolute;
top: 475px;
left: 525px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 30pt;}
```

YouTube_Advance_Heading.js

```
My_Timer = setInterval(Display_Text, 100);


function Setup() {

   var User_Screen_Width
   var User_Screen_Height
   var Text_Width
   var Text_Height
   var Text_Array
   var Text_Array_Counter
   var Text
   var My_Timer
   var My_Timer_2
   var My_Timer_3
   var Point_Value
   var Screen_Position
   var Style_Collection
   var Fade_Number

   Text_Arrays = new Array(0, 27, 50, 75, 95, 122, 151, 174, 199, 217, 245, 
   274,  292, 317, 341, 365, 390, 414, 439, 463, 487, 512, 536, 561, 585, 
   609, 634, 658, 683, 707, 731, 756, 780, 805, 829, 853, 878, 902, 927, 
   951, 975);
   document.getElementById("Point_Values").value = 0;
   document.getElementById("F_Photo").value = 0;
   document.getElementById("My_Image").style.opacity = 0.01
   document.getElementById("Winner_Text").style.opacity = 0.01


}

function Display_Text() {

     Point_Value = document.getElementById("Point_Values").value;

     if(Point_Value < 40) {

          Point_Value = parseInt(Point_Value);
          User_Screen_Width = screen.availWidth;
          Text_Array_Counter = Point_Value;
          Text_Width = Text_Arrays[Text_Array_Counter];
          Screen_Position = User_Screen_Width - Text_Width;
          Screen_Position = Screen_Position / 2;
          Style_Collection = "left: " + Screen_Position + "px; ";
          Style_Collection = Style_Collection + "font-size: " + Point_Value 
          + "pt; ";  
          document.getElementById("S_Collection").value = Style_Collection;
          document.getElementById("My_Heading").style.cssText = 
          Style_Collection;
          Point_Value = Point_Value + 1;}

     if (Point_Value == 40) {


         document.getElementById("Raise_My_Text").value = 300;


         clearInterval(My_Timer);
         My_Timer_2 = setInterval(Raise_Text, 100);}    

      else {

          document.getElementById("Point_Values").value = Point_Value;

      }  

}

function Raise_Text() {

    Text_Height = document.getElementById("Raise_My_Text").value;


    if(Text_Height > 100) {

          Fade_Number = document.getElementById("F_Photo").value;
          Fade_Number = parseFloat(Fade_Number);
          Fade_Number = Fade_Number + .00017
          document.getElementById("T_Height").value = Fade_Number;
          document.getElementById("My_Image").style.opacity = Fade_Number;
          document.getElementById("Winner_Text").style.opacity = 
          Fade_Number;

          if(Fade_Number < 1) {

               document.getElementById("F_Photo").value = Fade_Number;}

          Style_Collection = document.getElementById("S_Collection").value;
          document.getElementById("My_Heading").style.cssText = 
          Style_Collection;
          Text_Height = document.getElementById("Raise_My_Text").value;
          Text_Height = Text_Height - 3;
          Style_Collection = Style_Collection + "top: " + Text_Height + 
          "px;";
          document.getElementById("My_Heading").style.cssText = 
          Style_Collection;
          document.getElementById("Raise_My_Text").value = Text_Height;}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The final opacity was way too low. So on line 79 of your js file, I removed a couple "0"s and it worked.

```
Fade_Number = Fade_Number + .017
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I really appreciate it.